# Wordpress site URL changed; how to fix it without database access?

Tags: database, urls

we would like your assist on an error that occurred during some changes on the admin panel. We have this site called Caid.gr , it's for a non-profit company. We changed the Wordpress site URL by mistake, we wanted to change the Site URL only. Now we cant log in again to the Admin Panel. We dont have access to the Database, is there a way to reverse these changes?|

Hoping for a solution, thank you for your time!

Comment: Do you have FTP?

Answer (score 3):

See [Changing The Site URL « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) for recovery instructions on how to reset the URLs *without database access*, i.e. by editing either the `wp-config.php` file or the theme's `functions.php` file with FTP:

1) by adding lines to wp-config.php (which can be left in place):

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

2) or the theme's functions.php file (but remove these after reloading the site a few times, as they write to the database).

```
update_option('siteurl','http://example.com');
update_option('home','http://example.com');
```

Comment: yeah I have seen those things before but I am not very familiar with Database , and to be honest I dont access to it, I didnt create the site at the first time , but thank your for trying to help

Comment: The methods I posted *do not* require database access.